# App that tracks a specific tag

Tags: discussion, app-request

I'm looking for a software like `StackTracker` that allows to track a specific tag on `StackExchange` sites.

Do you know some?

Comment: Would a tool that provides an RSS feed for a tag work alright? What OS are you using?

Comment: Yes it could work. I would need a feed reader that stays in taskbar then. I'm using Win7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to [StackGuru](https://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-jabber-bot-for-all-stackapps-sites), it's awesome.

> StackGuru is a Jabber/XMPP bot which
>   gives you a command line interface to
>   Stackapps sites, including
>   Stackoverflow, Serverfault and
>   Superuser. **The bot allows you to
>   follow questions tags by giving you a
>   notification each time a new question
>   is ask on the followed tag**. You can
>   also follow a question which will send
>   you a notification each time someone
>   post a comment or an answer on the
>   question.

Answer (score 2):

What about just using the RSS feed for the tag?

e.g. https://stackapps.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=app-request&sort=newest

If you click on a tag, then the RSS feed link is down the bottom on the left.

Comment: ...or use Stack2RSS for added functionality.

Comment: @George - I highly recommend linking in comments as well (i.e. [Stack2RSS](http://stackapps.com/q/1599)): despite doing it manually is a bit cumbersome, and even usability/convenience for the readers aside, the link building and visibility effects within one SE site are specifically worth it, see block *Linked* within ride sidebar (guess you are aware of it, just a reminder for promotional purposes ;)